# What do I do about unequal sampling probabilities for second-stage sampling units in a PPS sample?

Tags: survey-sampling, survey-weights

Say that I am drawing a two-stage simple random sample. The first stage selectes a unit that is a cluster, the second stage selects units within the cluster.

There are two different types of units to be sampled within the cluster, and for one type, there is only one unit in each cluster - call them Pr. This means that the selection of the cluster, or primary sampling unit, is the same thing as selecting a Pr for the sample. Every PSU has an equal chance of selection into the sample, therefore every Pr has an equal chance of selection.

Now say that the PSUs will be sampled by probability proportional so size. (The size variable for each PSU is related to the other group that will be sampled.) Each Pr has the same chance of selection as the cluster they are within - but they no longer all have an equal chance of selection.

Can this be corrected for by weighting? Is the weight for each Pr the inverse of the selection probability of each PSU?